# Meteor build process makes images in running app disappear

Tags: image, meteor, build

Noticed this behaviour in my meteor app and couldn't find anything online about it, not a huge deal but I'm curious about what's going on in the background.

So the meteor app is currently running on an AWS server (ubuntu 14.04.5). I have tested this behaviour while the app is running using `forever` package and `pm2` package.

The frontend client will be fine running on the AWS server but once I start a build process (ie. `meteor build`), all of the images in the running app will disappear/break. To avoid this, we take the application down before starting the build process but it would be very nice to be able to build and have the running app still work fine.

Anyone have any ideas about why this might be happening? I couldn't find much documentation on the specific details of the meteor build process but I assume it has something to do with the `/public` folder being moved away.

Interestingly, once the build process is complete (new bundle has been created, old bundle is still running) the images will reappear on the running app.

Comment: how are you running the meteor app? And where are you building to?

Comment: After running ```meteor build ../buildDir``` (so 1 level outside of the project directory), we unzip the tar, go into ```bundle/programs/server npm i``` and then ```forever start main.js``` or ```pm2 start main.js``` from the bundle.

Comment: thanks; then I don't understand how that can make anything disappear from the running app.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, the whole point of this was to build/deploy a new bundle of the meteor app while the old one is still running in order to have (basically) 0 downtime for deployments. Do you have any idea if that is possible? I was looking into ```mup``` but haven't gotten a chance to try it out yet

Comment: Yes, mup does that out of the box, but the "usual" `meteor build` and deploy flow should allow you to do that, too. SO I'm still not sure what's going wrong in your case with those images. As long as your new `meteor build` will not write into the directories being hosted at that time, it shouldn't interfere.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight! I'll try out mup when I get a chance but if it does the same building process just automated, might be the same issue. Either way, I'll have to come back to this later on but I appreciate the help!

Comment: No, mup has it's own build process. It uses docker images.

Comment: Even better! Will update here once I've tried it out